# undefined offset while checking for empty array

Tags: php

I have an array like this i want to remove the last array which does not have any values

i used array-filter but its not filtering the array after filter it should

get 0,1,2 only .

```
$res_arr= array(
    0=>array(1,2,3,6,7),
    1=>array(7,5,3,8),
2=>array(6,5,9,8),
3=>array(),
);

$array1=array();

foreach($res_arr as $array_key=>$array_item)
{
  if($array1[$array_key] == 0)
  {
    unset($array1[$array_key]);
  }
}

 print_r($array1);
```

Above code i get
Undefined offset: 0
Undefined offset: 1
Undefined offset: 2

Comment: what is your `$array1` values?

Comment: `$array1` is empty, there're no elements and this causes warnings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short-cut method.

```
$new_arr=array_filter($res_arr,'count');
print_r($new_arr);
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/99406)

---

### The long way..

You could so something like this

```
<?php
$res_arr= array(
    0=>array(1,2,3,6,7),
    1=>array(7,5,3,8),
    2=>array(6,5,9,8),
    3=>array(),
);

$i=0;
foreach($res_arr as $arr)
{
    if(count($arr)==0)
    {
        unset($res_arr[$i]);
    }
    $i++;
}
print_r($res_arr);
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 6
            [4] => 7
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 8
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 9
            [3] => 8
        )

)
```

Comment: `foreach` allows you to dynamically access the keys of an array, doing so manually seems downright foolish.

Answer (score 4):

Using `array_filter`:

```
$res_arr= array(
    0=>array(1,2,3,6,7),
    1=>array(7,5,3,8),
    2=>array(6,5,9,8),
    3=>array(),
);
$r = array_filter($res_arr, function($v) { return !empty($v); });
print_r($r);
```